# 2D char arrays in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, char, 2d

I found weird things in the following. I am new and do not know what this does.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

 char y[]={"NO Error"};//This supposed to be 2D array ?! No Error! Did not write y[][]!
 char x[][10]={"No Error0","No Error1","No Error2"};//This also is a 2D array! and just fine.
 char z[]={"Compile time Error","Compile time Error"};//Compile time Error! not like y[]!
 printf("%s ",x[2]);            //Output is "No Error2"! and fine.
 printf("%s ",x[2][4]);         //Runtime Error!I thought output will be "E".
 printf("\n%s ",y);             //Output is "NO Error" ! , No Problems .
 printf("\n%s ",y[0]);          //Runtime Error!
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x[2][4]` is a `char` not a string. So using `%s` in the `printf` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Printf with %s looks for the string.  Beyond that I believe you are pushing your luck with the data there.  Technically y[] is a pointer to a char array, but it does not keep track of how you use that data.  Fortunately you are putting character values into the "array" and it will still find the correct null terminator that printf is looking for to print a string.  If you want to print a specific character you would need to use %c but that would be trying to access uninitialized memory...

Comment: What about other errors ?

Comment: You did not get an error for the first, because you can always use the braces in an initializer: `int i = {1};`. But try to add a second-string literal (see examle 3) and your compiler shall complain (if not, instantly burn the compiler, spead the ashes and salt the harddisk it was stored)!

Comment: Thanks All , i got answer.

Answer (score 0):

A string works as a char array. So in y[] a single string will fit. In x[][10] an array of strings will fit. But in z[] an array of strings will not fit.

Furthermore, in your printf, %s is string (actually a char*). In your second printf, you're using a char instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your code  analysis

> char y[]={"NO Error"};

Is not 2D array, it is simple 1D character array.
In Next

> char z[]={"Compile time Error","Compile time Error"};

You initialize array of string( 2D Character array) to character array.
This should be like

```
 char z[][100]={"Compile time Error","Compile time Error"};
```

Your code

> printf("\n%s ",y[0]);

Is wrong as y is not 2D array as `y[0]` point only character, you can write

```
printf("\n%c ",y);  //Output N
```